# how to put a view off-screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Is it able to put views to the left, but off-screen?

I want display three views(images) but only the second fit on the screen, something like:

```
    +---------------------+
    |       Screen        |
+-------+  +-------+  +-------+
|       |  |       |  |       |
| image |  | image |  | image |
|       |  |       |  |       |
+-------+  +-------+  +-------+
    |                     |
    +---------------------+
```

I would like to start be visible in this form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use several approaches:

- `Gallery` (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)
- `HorizontalScrollView` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)
- `ViewPager` (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

The choice now depends on what exactly you want to perform in your app.

Hope this helps! 
In case you need something more specific, please shoot it!

Comment: I write code which put views in (relativelayout) but on load shows me from the left first view, second, third. But I want to shows this exactly: 1/2 view, 1 view, 1/2 view - second view on center, immediately after loading :(

Comment: In that case, I would reject ViewPager and HorizontalScrollView solution. You can use the Gallery and set the current item to the second image. Since the image is not full screen, the other two images will be also shown.

Answer (score 1):

In xml, try using:

```
android:paddingLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it with RelativeLayout. i think it is kind of like floating div in HTML, very funny.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/left_body"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:background="@drawable/house"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/right_body"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:background="@drawable/house"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/main_body"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_body"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:background="@drawable/house"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```